# ISAPI Rewrite syntax help for redirecting from .htm page to .aspx page

Tags: isapi, isapi-redirect

I want to rewrite(301 redirect) www.mydomain.com\default.htm to www.mydomain.com\HomePage.aspx. This way I need to do for each htm page in my site to different aspx page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule default.htm /HomePage.aspx [I,U,L]
```

I think this will do, but if you are running on IIS you could also take a look into URL Rewrite Module 2.0

I think i got the flags wrong:
    `RewriteRule Default.htm HomePage.aspx [NC,R=301,L]`

*Should* do the trick.
Nethertheless ISAPI_Rewrite is quite well documented at ["ISAPI Rewrite Examples"](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/examples.htm)

Comment: As my site is hosted in third party web server, only way to do 301 redirect is to use httpd.ini file. I have included this in that.But not working.